# Google Colab Pro crashed while allocating large memory

Tags: tensorflow, out-of-memory, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to use Colab pro GPU (max 25Gb memory) for training a sequential model.
Based on the instructions found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/guide/gpu.ipynb#scrollTo=2qO2cS9QFn42), I'm setting the memory limit to 22Gb. Below is my code and logs.

```
import tensorflow as tf
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
mem_limit=22000

gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  try:
    tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration(
        gpus[0],
        [tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=mem_limit)])
    logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
  except RuntimeError as e:
    # Virtual devices must be set before GPUs have been initialized
    print(e)
```

**Per this log, it seems to be setting the cap**

```
Dec 22, 2020, 7:57:15 PM    WARNING 2020-12-23 01:57:15.673093: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 22000 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 6.0)

Dec 22, 2020, 7:57:15 PM    WARNING 2020-12-23 01:57:15.673030: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:39] Overriding allow_growth setting because the TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH environment variable is set. Original config value was 0.
```

However, when executing a statement, invariably it's attempting to allocate 37Gb memory and the runtime crashes. Here is the log

```
Dec 22, 2020, 8:01:01 PM    INFO    KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports

Dec 22, 2020, 8:00:47 PM    WARNING tcmalloc: large alloc 37200994304 bytes == 0x7f48b828a000 @ 0x7f5249f5a001 0x7f52414564ff 0x7f52414a6ab8 0x7f52414aabb7 0x7f5241549003 0x50a4a5 0x50cc96 0x507be4 0x509900 0x50a2fd 0x50cc96 0x507be4 0x5161c5 0x50a12f 0x50beb4 0x507be4 0x509900 0x50a2fd 0x50beb4 0x507be4 0x509900 0x50a2fd 0x50cc96 0x507be4 0x508ec2 0x594a01 0x59fd0e 0x50d256 0x507be4 0x509900 0x50a2fd
```

My dataset is large and will possibly require more than 128Gb memory. Is there way to limit the amount of memory use by TF and I'm fine with longer execution time, if it comes to that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue and had to change my tf code. Setting the maximum GPU memory does not mean that tf will figure out a way to run your code without trying to allocate more than what you have specified. That works for what I would call "units" of allocation but if one single operation is gigantic, it will blow up.

So, let's supposed that you have a massive matrix multiplication that can't fit on the GPU. Colab will crash.

Based on my limited experience, you have 2 options:

1. Change your settings not to use GPU ( and bare the performance hit)
2. Change your code