# What is the alternative method for one-hot or hashing

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I have a sample dataset of 60k sentences and trying to create a sequence model.
After cleaning, preprocessing my length of 'y' is 573,806 rows. The length of the unique tokens is 16207.

In order to use it in the Embedding layer, I'm trying to convert this 'y' to a binary class. I have tried one-hot encoding, to_categorical, and hashing. All these methods demand substantial memory allocation (37Gb) and my google Colab Pro crashes.

There seems to be no way to avoid the crash caused by over memory allocation. [Here is my related SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65418230/google-colab-pro-crashed-while-allocating-large-memory)

Given this, I'm looking for some guidance for this problem. Are there any other alternate memory efficient methods available to solve this problem that would work with sequential models?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of representing the data as one hot encoded vectors which is computationally expensive as you found out what you can do is make use of `embedding columns` which is able to embed higher dimensional data into a lower dimensional vector space, thus reducing the total number of columns needed.

#### Representing days of the week using one-hot encoding

[image]

#### Representing days of the week using embeddings

[image]

Tensorflow has `tf.feature_column.embedding_column()` for this and you can find out more from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/embedding_column).

However do note that the argument `categorical_column` needs to be created by the `tf.feature_column.categorical_column()` function.

```
embedding_column = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(
    categorical_column=categorical_column,
    dimension=dimension_of_embedding_vector)
```

The `dimension_of_embedding_vector` formula is more of a rule of thumb than anything and is based on this formula and there is more information from this [Google BlogPost](https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/introducing-tensorflow-feature-columns.html) they use the 4th root of the number of categories. :

```
embedding_dimensions =  number_of_categories**0.25
```

Another formula is by Jeremy Howard(founder of fast.ai) where he recommends using:

```
embedding size = min(50, number of categories/2).
```

Comment: @yudhish - thanks for the suggestion. using categorical_column/embedding_column helps but embedding_dimensions math isn't working out. Both the formulas result in very low number of dim and I get this error "indices[0,15] = 415 is not in [0, 50)". Increasing the dim works but results in increasing negative loss and accuracy never improve.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I recommend you process the sentences.  For convenience lets call the column in the data set 'sentence' and assume you have read in the dataframe as the variable data
code is below

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
def get_sequences(texts):
    tokenizer = Tokenizer()
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)
    
    vocab_length = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
    print("Vocab length:", vocab_length)
    
    sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(texts)
    
    max_seq_length = np.max([len(sequence) for sequence in sequences])
    print("Max sequence length:", max_seq_length)
    
    sequences = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=max_seq_length, padding='post')
    
    return sequences

 sentence_sequences = get_sequences(data['sentence'])
 df = data.drop('sentence', axis=1)
```

you can now feed the sentence_sequences into a keras embedding layer in your model

```
emb_dim =64  # user defined dimension I find 64 usually works well
sentence_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
    input_dim=max_seq_length,output_dim=emb_dim,
    input_length=sentence_sequences.shape[1],
    name='sentence_embedding')(sentence_sequences)
```

If you have other features besides the sentences then you can create them as separate inputs to the model. Processes them, flatten the result and then concatenate them with
sentence embedding. Put the result of that into a dense layer where the number of neurons
is the same as the number of classes and use a softmax activation.
For a good video tutorial on how to process text I recommend to go [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzWbbqgjV9g&list=PLs_CQl4mUvI7Z9HnwoeOS5EUu9gyvekjK&index=120&ab_channel=GabrielAtkin)

Answer (score 0):

I thought of leaving an answer here might help someone in future

The model architecture is the same for all the different methods attempted below.

**when y is one-hot encoded using to_categrical**

Epoch 10/10
30/30 [==============================] - 7s 245ms/step - loss: 0.0116 - accuracy: 0.6046

**when y is build from categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list --> embedding_column which produces vectors**

Epoch 10/10
30/30 [==============================] - 8s 266ms/step - loss: -0.0012 - accuracy: 0.0084

**when y is build from feature_column.bucketized_column --> indicator_column which produdes one-hot encoding**

Epoch 10/10
30/30 [==============================] - 7s 248ms/step - loss: 0.0113 - accuracy: 0.6160

**when y is built from categorical_column_with_hash_bucket (max features)--> embedding_column (max features) which produces vectors**

Epoch 10/10
30/30 [==============================] - 7s 229ms/step - loss: -0.0365 - accuracy: 0.0398

**when y is built from crossed_column, embedding_column which produces vectors, the performance is almost the same as hash_bucket approach.**

Given these experiments, I've redesigned the logic to use DataGenerator approach and iteratively train the whole dataset using one-hot encoding. This method fits within available memory, takes longer duration for training but that's yielding much better accuracy.